# Is there an OS-independent way to map iSCSI name (iqn) to IP?

Tags: wmi, iscsi, wbem

I have a series of iSCSI names (initiators) that typically look like this:

```
iqn.yyyy-mm.naming-authority:unique name
```

E.g.

```
iqn.1991-05.com.microsoft:myPC
```

I would like to programatically **map such iSCSI names to their respective IP addresses and/or hostnames** - is there a way to do that? Ideally:

- I'd like to obtain the hostname using e.g. CIM-XML/WBEM/SMI-S or a similar protocol that would allow me to perform the mapping in a platform-independent manner;
- I'd like to avoid having to deploy any custom code to the hosts;
- I'd like to avoid having to manually connect to each possible host in the network and check if its iSCSI name matches the one in question.
- Java or C# preferred.

Note that the `unique name` part is *usually* a hostname, but there is no guarantee for that. Alternatively, iSCSI names can use [EUI format](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-4-esx-vcenter/index.jsp?topic=/com.vmware.vsphere.server_configclassic.doc_41/esx_server_config/introduction_to_storage/c_understanding_iscsi_naming_and_addressing.html), e.g.:

```
eui.0123456789ABCDEF
```

On Windows, either "iSCSI Initiator" control panel utility or `iscsicli.exe` command can be used to retrieve the machine's IQN, so theoretically I could iterate all possible (Windows) hosts and see if the IQN values match; however, this doesn't sound like an optimal solution.

I also dumped all WMI and [CIM classes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa386179%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to look for this mapping, but couldn't find it there.

Is there a proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The iSNS protocol was created to handle that task (among others).